# Why does Yii-enforced authentication only work on the homepage/static pages?

Tags: authentication, yii

I need to enforce authentication across all pages of a YII application. To do this I've extended the `SiteController` class with the following code I got from http://www.heirbaut.nl/2010/02/23/forcing-a-yii-application-to-authenticate/:

```
/**
 * @return array action filters
 */
public function filters(){
    return array(
        'accessControl', // perform access control for CRUD operations
    );
}

/**
 * Specifies the access control rules.
 * This method is used by the 'accessControl' filter.
 * @return array access control rules
 */
public function accessRules(){
    return array(
        array('allow',  // allow all users to perform 'login'
            'actions'=>array('login'),
            'users'=>array('*'),
        ),
        array('allow', // allow authenticated user to perform any action
            'users'=>array('@'),
        ),
        array('deny',  // deny all users
            'users'=>array('*'),
        ),
    );
}
```

This only does what it's supposed to, redirect all requests for unauthenticaed users to the login form, for the `index.php` url. But `index.php?r=person` and consequentially, the main menu of the application bypasses this restriction and show up regardless of authenthication.

Comment: Do you have a `PersonController`?

Comment: yes. does every single Controller need to reference that same code? if you say it does, of course ill rather create a new class to inherit from. but that seems like a lot of boiler plate code. can i not fix this issue higher up the chain in Yii?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every controller needs to reference that code. An option is to create your own controller that extends `CController` and place it in your `protected/components` folder

```
class MyController extends CController{
    /**
     * @return array action filters
     */
    public function filters(){
        return array(
            'accessControl', // perform access control for CRUD operations
        );
    }

    /**
     * Specifies the access control rules.
     * This method is used by the 'accessControl' filter.
     * @return array access control rules
     */
    public function accessRules(){
        return array(
            array('allow', // allow authenticated user to perform any action
                'users'=>array('@'),
            ),
            array('deny',  // deny all users
                'users'=>array('*'),
            ),
        );
    }
}
```

Then in your controller classes you need to extend `MyController` and override `accessRules()` to add any additional rules

```
public class SiteController extends MyController{

    ...

    public function accessRules(){
        $rules=parent::accessRules();
        array_unshift($rules,array(
            'allow',  // allow all users to perform 'login'
            'actions'=>array('login'),
            'users'=>array('*'),
        ));
        return $rules;
    }

    ...
}
```